# Problem with Match function returning Type Mismatch (VBA EXCEL)

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error when using the Match function and I can't find the problem, would you please help me?
I would like also to know if we can do the same using the Find function.

I have named range called `DataListName`, it's located in a sheet "Data" (ID name) or "Database" (sheet name)
the DataListName represent the colum C

DataListName=Database!$C:$C

I am trying to find the row in the column C, the text `ListABC`

Here is my code:

```
Dim ListNameArr As Variant
Dim LookupRow As Long
Dim ListNameValue As String


ListNameValue ="ListABC"

With wsData

ListNameArr = .Range("DataListName").Value

LookupRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ListNameValue, ListNameArr, 0)

end with
```

Anyone can explains to me where is the error please ? and if I can do the same with the Find method, how and which is better ?

EDIT :

If i replace as suggested

```
LookupRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ListNameValue, ListNameArr, 0)
```

by

`LookupRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ListNameValue, .Range("DataListName"), 0)`, I don't have type mismatch anymore, but another error,

> Run time error '1004' Unable to get the Match propertyof the
>   WorksheetFunction class

Just for information if it may Help, I have another workbook open, in fact my workbook open another one, but as you can see in my code, I have a reference for the ws.data, so I don't know if the fact of opening another workbook cause this error or what

Comment: `ListNameArr = .Range("DataListName").Value` creates a two dimensional array and MATCH does not work with 2D arrays.  Just use the range in the MATCH:  `LookupRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ListNameValue, .Range("DataListName"), 0)`

Comment: Ah I didn't know that Match doesn't support two dimensional array, I will give it a try and let you know...Would you please tell me how to do that with find ? I read that find and match does the same and what is better ?

Comment: and by the way, the fact that I add the .value that creates the 2 dimentional array ?

Comment: For single column lookup match is quicker.  I do not use Find that much at all, so I cannot help outside what is already written by MicroSoft in their own documentation.

Comment: OK, in my case, it's better to use Match then, because anyway I have only 1 column in which I am looking for the value. if I do .Range("DataListName").value it will become 2 dimensional ? it's the .value that makes it 2 dimensions ?

Comment: It is the nature of bulk filling from a vertical range, that the array becomes two dimensional.  a 1 dimensional array is horizontal.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks a lot for the information it's the first time that I know this, do you have any link that explains that ? what is the first dimenson and what is the second one in the case of 1 vertical column ?

Comment: The second dimension will be `1` for one column the first dimension will be the number of rows.

Comment: If I put this, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ListNameValue, .Range("DataListName"), 0), I don't have type mismatch anymore, but another error, 1004, unable to read the match property of the class worksheetfunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, when you set the range to value, you're doing a 2-dim array which `Match` won't support. Instead rewrite your code as follows:

```
Dim ListNameArr As Range, LookupRow As Long, ListNameValue As String

ListNameValue = "ListABC"

Set ListNameArr = wsData.Range("DataListName")

LookupRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ListNameValue, ListNameArr, 0)
```

Here is how you could leverage `Find` for column C and return the row. Hopefully you can adjust as needed if you want to change the search range.

```
LookupRow = ListNameArr.Cells.Find(What:=ListNameValue, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False).Row
```

[Here's some other examples](https://pastebin.com/HtLG5Bmh) of using the find function you may find useful:

```
Sub Find_Example_WithLoop()
    Dim CL As Range, FirstFoundAddress As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ActiveSheet

'FIND SYNTAX By PGCodeRider

'LOOKIN: xlFormulas , xlValues , or xlNotes
'LookAT: xlWhole or XlPart
'SearchOrder: xlByRows or xlByColumns
'SearchDirection: xlNext or xlPrevious
'MatchCase: True or False
'FindNext - Continues a search that was begun with the Find method. Finds the next cell that matches those same conditions.

    ' Find first instance on sheet
   Set CL = WS.Cells.Find(What:="BOOOOM", _
        After:=WS.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not CL Is Nothing Then
        ' if found, remember location, else ends if-statement

        FirstFoundAddress = CL.Address

        Do
            'DO SOMETHING!!

            ' find next instance
           Set CL = WS.Cells.FindNext(After:=CL)
            ' repeat until finds original cell
       Loop Until FirstFoundAddress = CL.Address

    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here's an example of match being used with a method to handle errors if nothing found:

```
Sub matchExample()
Dim text2match As String: text2match = "matchME"
Dim rng2Match As Range: Set rng2Match = Range("A:A")


'should return an integer
On Error GoTo notGOOD
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(text2match, rng2Match, 0)
On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

notGOOD:
MsgBox "Couldn't find " & text2match


End Sub
```

Comment: I will tag your answer as picked answer even if It wasn't what I used at the end, but because you did the effort to help, you deserve to get the reputation rewards. thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to bypass the error

```
Dim Var As Variant
Var = Application.Match(ListNameValue, .Range("DataListName"), 0)
If Not IsError(Var) Then
LookupRow = CLng(Var)
Else
LookupRow = 0
```

End If

Comment: Why not drop the ‘Not’ and reverse the if/else conditions? A little less complicated.

Comment: because the code inside the Not iserror is a big code this is a part of the code, the code in the else is only one line lookupronw=0, so I prefere to have the big code above I find that easiar to read